# add five items on list to each value in column of dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

Not really sure how to phrase the title, but what I have a list of names in a dataframe and I would like to add five items from a list to each name such that each name and one item is a row. So,

```
Name 1, Item1

Name 1, Item2

Name 1, Item3

Name 1, Item4
```

Example data:

```
testdata<-as_tibble(c("Steve","Paul","Mary"))
product<-c("Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(testdata, product)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
   value product
   <chr> <chr>  
 1 Mary  Item1  
 2 Mary  Item2  
 3 Mary  Item3  
 4 Mary  Item4  
 5 Mary  Item5  
 6 Paul  Item1  
 7 Paul  Item2  
 8 Paul  Item3  
 9 Paul  Item4  
10 Paul  Item5  
11 Steve Item1  
12 Steve Item2  
13 Steve Item3  
14 Steve Item4  
15 Steve Item5
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `merge` to perform such cross join.

```
merge(testdata, product)

#   value     y
#1  Steve Item1
#2   Paul Item1
#3   Mary Item1
#4  Steve Item2
#5   Paul Item2
#6   Mary Item2
#7  Steve Item3
#8   Paul Item3
#9   Mary Item3
#10 Steve Item4
#11  Paul Item4
#12  Mary Item4
#13 Steve Item5
#14  Paul Item5
#15  Mary Item5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
with(
  testdata,
  rev(expand.grid(Item = product, Name = value))
)
```

which gives

```
    Name  Item
1  Steve Item1
2  Steve Item2
3  Steve Item3
4  Steve Item4
5  Steve Item5
6   Paul Item1
7   Paul Item2
8   Paul Item3
9   Paul Item4
10  Paul Item5
11  Mary Item1
12  Mary Item2
13  Mary Item3
14  Mary Item4
15  Mary Item5
```